# Duda con objetos y tablas en JS

Tags: javascript, poo, bucle-for

Estoy empezando con JS y tengo una duda sobre los **objetos** y como pintar su contenido en **tablas**.

He creado una tabla con **3 columnas**, con PELICULA, AÑO y PAIS.

Dentro de cada una de esas columnas quiero añadir los datos del objeto película, pero no lo consigo.

Lo intenté de varias formas pero no me sale:

¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que me aparezca cada cosa en su columna?

En la **primera forma** lo hice del siguiente modo y me crea muchos  con un :

```
'use strict'

//Array del objeto

var peliculas = [
    {titulo: 'La verdad duele', year: 2014, pais: 'UK'},
    {titulo: 'Diamantes de sangre', year: 2010, pais: 'EEUU'},
    {titulo: 'Agora', year: 2009, pais: 'España'}
]

//Recorrer peliculas

var listaPeliculas = document.querySelector(".listaPeliculas");

for (const indice in peliculas) {
   let tr = document.createElement("tr");
   let td = document.createElement("td");
   //Titulo
   td.append(peliculas[indice].titulo);
   tr.append(td);
   listaPeliculas.append(tr);
}


for (const year in peliculas) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");

    //Año
    td.append(peliculas[year].year);
    tr.append(td);
    listaPeliculas.append(tr);
}
```

En la **segunda forma** lo hice de este modo y solo me aparece la última película y no sé porqué. Para ello creado en el html esto:

```
<tr>
    <td id="pelicula"></td>
    <td id="anio"></td>
    <td id="pais"></td>
</tr>
```

```
'use strict'


//Array del objeto

var peliculas = [
    {titulo: 'La verdad duele', year: 2014, pais: 'UK'},
    {titulo: 'Diamantes de sangre', year: 2010, pais: 'EEUU'},
    {titulo: 'Agora', year: 2009, pais: 'España'}
]

console.log(peliculas);

//Recorrer peliculas


var pelicula = document.querySelector("#pelicula");
var anio = document.querySelector("#anio");
var pais = document.querySelector("#pais");

for (const indice in peliculas) {

    pelicula.innerHTML = peliculas[indice].titulo;
    anio.innerHTML = peliculas[indice].year;
    pais.innerHTML = peliculas[indice].pais;
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar,
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios fallos en tu codigo que intentare explicartelo.

**Primera forma:**

1. Utilizar `querySelector` es un poco arriesgado, ya que solo devuelve el primer elemento. ¿Que pasa si el selector(**.listaPeliculas**) se utiliza en un elemento que no es?
2. No es necesario recorrer cada clave del objeto por separado, tal y como lo estas haciendo para titulo y año.

**Segundo paso:**

1. Cuando haces `innerHTML` no es acumulativo. Es decir siempre te pondra el ultimo registro.

En total tu codigo con unos cambios quedaria algo asi.

```js
'use strict'

//Array del objeto
var peliculas = [
    {titulo: 'La verdad duele', year: 2014, pais: 'UK'},
    {titulo: 'Diamantes de sangre', year: 2010, pais: 'EEUU'},
    {titulo: 'Agora', year: 2009, pais: 'España'}
]
//Tabla con los contenidos
var listaPeliculas = document.getElementById('tabla');

//Aqui vamos a guardar los tr y td con su informacion.
let tablaContent = ``

//Recoremos las peliculas
//El operador in es para obtener el indice, 
//en cambio of es el objeto en si.

for (const item of peliculas) {
  //Fijate que utilizamos += para acumular los datos. 
  //Template strings syntax
   tablaContent += `
    <tr>
      <td>${item.titulo}</td>
      <td>${item.year}</td>
      <td>${item.pais}</td>
    </td>
  
  `
}
//Finalmente añadimos el contenido a la tabla
listaPeliculas.innerHTML += tablaContent
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Añadimos el id a la tabla-->
  <table id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <th id="pelicula">TITULO</th>
      <th id="anio">AÑO</th>
      <th id="pais">PAIS</th>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Eugeni por tu clara explicación y los tips sobre mi código. La verdad que me ha resultado bastante sencillo de esta forma, la aplicaré para futuros proyectos.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este es lo que buscas.

```js
function buildTable(labels, objects, container) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  var theadTr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var theadTh = document.createElement('th');
    theadTh.innerHTML = labels[i];
    theadTr.appendChild(theadTh);
  }
  thead.appendChild(theadTr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  for (j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
    var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (k = 0; k < labels.length; k++) {
      var tbodyTd = document.createElement('td');
      tbodyTd.innerHTML = objects[j][labels[k].toLowerCase()];
      tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTd);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  container.appendChild(table);
}



var labels3 = ['ID', 'MOVIE TITLE' ,'YEAR', 'COUNTRY'];
var objects3 = [
  {"id": "1",  'movie title': "La verdad duele",  'year': "2014",  'country': "UK"},
  {"id": "1",  'movie title': "Diamantes de sangre",  'year': "2010",  'country': "EEUU"},
  {"id": "1",  'movie title': "Agora",  'year': "2009",  'country': "SPAIN"}
];

buildTable(labels3, objects3, document.getElementById('c'));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="c"><p>LISTA DE PELICULAS</p></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Emerson, es una muy buena opción también, aunque me resulta más compleja para mi. Me la apunto igualmente!
Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Esto te valdría, aun que, la respuesta de Emerson es mas elaborada y reusable que esta

```js
'use strict'


//Array del objeto

var peliculas = [
    {titulo: 'La verdad duele', year: 2014, pais: 'UK'},
    {titulo: 'Diamantes de sangre', year: 2010, pais: 'EEUU'},
    {titulo: 'Agora', year: 2009, pais: 'España'}
]

let tabla = document.getElementById("table");

for (const pelicula of peliculas) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let tdTitulo = document.createElement('td');
    let tdAnio = document.createElement('td');
    let tdPais = document.createElement('td');
    tdTitulo.innerText = pelicula.titulo;
    tdAnio.innerText = pelicula.year;
    tdPais.innerText = pelicula.pais;
    tr.appendChild(tdTitulo); 
    tr.appendChild(tdAnio); 
    tr.appendChild(tdPais);
    tabla.appendChild(tr); 
  }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Pelicula</th>
    <th>Año</th>
    <th>Pais</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias llsanchez, me gusta también mucho esta opción, muy aclaratoria, espero poder usarla.

Un saludo!